# How do I install git 1.8.3 on mac OSX?

Tags: macos, installation, git, package-management, version-control

I want to use the new `git submodule deinit` command added with 1.8.3.

Can someone give me step-by-step instructions on how to install and use the development version of git on mac OSX 10.7.5? The latest development version (1.8.3) is on github [here](https://github.com/git/git). What's the easiest way to install and use it? Can I use a package manager to install directly from the repo HEAD? Do I have to compile from the source? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try installing Git (HEAD) using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) by running `brew install git --HEAD`. This command will download the latest commit from the GitHub repository, compiles it and installs it, just like any other Homebrew package.

Answer (score 0):

Using a package manager (like port or brew) will only install the latest release (currently, my port installed git is at 1.8.2.2).

To be on the cutting edge, you'll need to get the latest code from github and build it yourself. There are plenty of sites specifying the steps - [here's one](http://ayanim97.com/mac/installing-and-upgrading-git-mac-os-lion), but you can find others.

Comment: Some package managers (like pip and cocoapods) let you install directly from the repo HEAD, which is why I asked about it. I'll check out your link, thanks.